# Get window.location.hostname in Ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have stored some base and redirect url values in database. I need to get the value of `window.location.hostname` from browser and check it in database. How can I pass this value to ruby code? I tried to do the following:

```
<script>
  var base_url = window.location.hostname;
  <% url_config = UrlConfig.find_by(base_url: base_url) %>
  if (window.location.pathname == "/") {
      window.location.href = url_config.redirect_url;
</script>
```

But I know this will not work since I cannot pass the value of Javascript variables to Ruby code like this. How can I get that value into the Ruby code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you'd like to redirect the user to a configured URL when they arrive on the home page.

If you are interacting with Ruby and the model (hence the database), I'd suggest not doing this in the view but in the controller via a `before_action`.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_action :redirect_to_configured_url, if: -> { current_path == root_path }

  # ...
  private

  def redirect_to_configured_url
    url_config = UrlConfig.find_by(base_url: base_url)
    redirect_to url_config.redirect_url if url_config # you also need to check if the UrlConfig was found
  end
end
```

Comment: Here what is the value of `root_path`? I have many `base_url`s. Can root_path have different values? i.e., is it the value equal to `request.host`?

Comment: root_path is always '/'. It points to the controller#method you have defined in `config/routes.rb`. ie: `root to: "home#index"`

Answer (score 0):

I could use `request` from `Rails`. I did it like this:

```
<script>
  var redirect_url = '<% UrlConfig.find_by(base_url: request.host).redirect_url %>';
  if (window.location.pathname == "/") {
      window.location.href = redirect_url;
  }
</script>
```

`request.host` gives the value of the host in the current url in browser. Then we can take the value and apply the logic.